# How to create array of objects in golang?

Tags: arrays, go, variable-assignment

I have a requirement in which I need to store array of objects in a variable. The objects are of different types. Refer to following example:

```
 v := [ {"name":"ravi"},
        ["art","coding","music","travel"],
        {"language":"golang"},
        {"experience":"no"}
      ]
```

Notice the second element is array of string itself. After research, I thought of storing this as interface type like:

```
 var v interface{} = [ {"name":"ravi"},
                       ["art","coding","music","travel"],
                       {"language":"golang"},
                       {"experience":"no"}
                     ]
```

Still, I am getting few compilation errors which I am not able to find out.

Comment: You have to define your data structures

Comment: Can someone point out the reasons for down votes, so that I can put my questions in a better way next time.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you're asking for is possible -- [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/PjUa4Yjx0C):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    v := []interface{}{
        map[string]string{"name": "ravi"},
        []string{"art", "coding", "music", "travel"},
        map[string]string{"language": "golang"},
        map[string]string{"experience": "no"},
    }
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

But you probably don't want to be doing this.  You're fighting the type system, I would question why you're using Go if you were doing it like this.  Consider leveraging the type system -- [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/oy1QfHgWKE):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type candidate struct {
    name string
    interests []string
    language string
    experience bool
}

func main() {
    candidates := []candidate{
        {
            name: "ravi",
            interests: []string{"art", "coding", "music", "travel"},
            language: "golang",
            experience: false,
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(candidates)
}
```

Comment: "I would question why you're using Go if you were doing it like this". They need to represent this data structure. You would advise using a different programming language if they have to work with data structures that are like that? Weird advise.

Answer (score -5):

Perfect python syntax, but go unfortunately use something less readable.
https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals