# Unmarshaling array of objects in Go

Tags: arrays, go

in GO, I've tried to produce the following json :

```
[["my",257.14,257.24],["txt", 121.11, 65.555]]
```

from a struct that's undergo unmarshaling - and i'm failing to do so.

Here is what I tried:

```
x := []MyStruct{{Zero: map[int]string{0: "str"}, One: map[int]float32{1: 5.6}, Two: map[int]float32{1: 5.88}}}
```

where MyStruct is :

```
type Timestamp struct {
  Zero      map[int]string      `json:"0"`
  One       map[int]float32     `json:"1"`
  Two       map[int]float32     `json:"2"`
}
```

this produces the wrong json structure:

```
"myStruct":[{"0":{"0":"has"},"1":{"1":5.6},"2":{"1":5.88}}]
```

tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031354/how-to-create-array-of-objects-in-golang) as well

any clue in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you want JSON arrays, why are you using maps? Do you need to start with that exact data structure?

Comment: ^. You need to use slices/arrays instead of maps. A map correlates to a JSON object, whereas a slice/array correlates to a list. Try `[]interface{}`, as opposed to `map[int]string` or `map[int]float32`, since you have a list of variable types.

Comment: @JimB yes, I need that exact struct. Can't figure a way to "unmarshal" it..

Comment: @Lansana could u please show an example?

Comment: You may need an adapter method that will convert one structure to another so that it will be unmarshalled correctly. You cannot have a direct 1:1 mapping for unmarshal in some cases based on unique requirements of data types, and yours may be such a case. For instance, pass in a slice of structs, return a slice of interface{} where the values are the values of the structs.

Comment: @Li3ro, your struct is a completely different structure form the JSON. Marshal/unmarshal with a structure that matches the JSON.

Comment: Let me know if my answer works for you.

Comment: Tnx- sorry for stalling.. checking your answer now. again Tnx m8!

Comment: please update `x := []MyStruct{{Zero: map[int]string{0: "str"}, One: map[int]float32{1: 5.6}, Two: map[int]float32{1: 5.88}}}` this as your expected

Comment: I don't understand why Two have key 1.

Comment: maybe your Zero/One/Two should be slice not map.

Comment: I'm confusing why you expect `[]MyStruct` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is your expected. It's possible to implement custom MarshalJSON/UnmarshalJSON.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Timestamp struct {
    Zero []string
    One  []float32
    Two  []float32
}

func (t *Timestamp) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var arr [][3]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &arr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    t.Zero = nil
    t.One = nil
    t.Two = nil
    for _, v := range arr {
        if len(v) != 3 {
            return errors.New("invalid json")
        }
        if s, ok := v[0].(string); ok {
            t.Zero = append(t.Zero, s)
        }
        if f, ok := v[1].(float64); ok {
            t.One = append(t.One, float32(f))
        }
        if f, ok := v[2].(float64); ok {
            t.Two = append(t.Two, float32(f))
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func (t *Timestamp) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var arr [][3]interface{}
    var max int
    if max < len(t.Zero) {
        max = len(t.Zero)
    }
    if max < len(t.One) {
        max = len(t.One)
    }
    if max < len(t.Two) {
        max = len(t.Two)
    }
    for i := 0; i < max; i++ {
        var v [3]interface{}
        if i < len(t.Zero) {
            v[0] = t.Zero[i]
        }
        if i < len(t.One) {
            v[1] = t.One[i]
        }
        if i < len(t.Two) {
            v[2] = t.Two[i]
        }
        arr = append(arr, v)
    }
    return json.Marshal(arr)
}

const j = `[["my",257.14,257.24],["txt", 121.11, 65.555]]`

func main() {
    var ts Timestamp
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &ts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    b, err := json.Marshal(&ts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/WtVEja1JDY

Comment: This worked for me so this is the accepted answer. Thank you both

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is you're trying to unmarshal a map, and a map will correlate to a JSON object. Your desired output is a list, so you need to unmarshal an array or a slice to get a list as your values.

Try making an adapter.

Small example:

```
type Object struct {
    Base   float32 
    Radius float32 
    Height float32 
    X      float32 
    Y      float32 
}

func (obj *Object) ToCircle() *Circle {
    return &Circle{
        Radius: obj.Radius,
        X:      obj.X,
        Y:      obj.Y,
    }
}

func (obj *Object) ToRectangle() *Rectangle {
    return &Rectangle{
        Base:   obj.Base,
        Height: obj.Height,
        X:      obj.X,
        Y:      obj.Y,
    }
}
```

In the example above, `Object` is converted to a `Rectangle` or a `Circle` using the `ToRectangle()` and `ToCircle()` adapters, respectively. In your case, you need to convert `Timestamp` to a `[]interface{}`. Then you can unmarshal and you'll just get a list of whatever values are in that slice, which is your desired output in this case.

For intsance, the signature if your adapter could look like this:

```
func (t *Timestamp) ToFoo() []interface{} {
    var ret []interface{}

    // Do some stuff to take values of 't' and append to 'ret'

    return ret
}

func main() {
    var result []interface{}

    json.Unmarshal(t.ToFoo(), &result)

    // ...
}
```

I'll leave the implementation details for you.

Comment: this compiles.. and I guess will work! but I cant test it since this little struct is part of a monster tree of structs I use, and when I need to unmarshal, It will unmarshal them all together. I wonder if there is a way to call this function on unmarshaling..

Comment: Oh I see.. hmm yeah I don't believe there is any sort of "callback" for unmarshal that gives you lifecycle access to do something like that. But you can try to call the adapter method on the monster struct recursively for every `Timestamp` property before unmarshalling.

Comment: @Lansana, of course there is. That's what the [`Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) and [`Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interfaces are.

Comment: @JimB Ah, good catch! I have not yet been exposed to those interfaces.